# element wise vector multiplication c++ (code not working)

Tags: c++, vector

I cannot seen to understand why my code does not work.
I have two vectors and I wish to substitute my second vector with the product of each element (`v2[0] = v1[0] * v2[0]`, `v2[1] = v1[1] * v2[1]` and so on...)

**code**

```
vector <float> vectorMultiplication(vector <float> &v1, vector <float> &v2)
{
    return std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), std::multiplies<float>() );
}
```

If anyone can point out my mistake, I will be very grateful.

P.S. The error message that my compiler throws is: 
`error: conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float> >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<float>’ requested`
P.S. 2 I am running C++98

Comment: hint: what is the return type of `std::transform`? What is the return type of your function? I know it is hard to believe, but sometimes rtfm really helps

Comment: `std::transform` does not return a container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: [`std::transform` returns an iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), you're returning a `vector<float>`, which cannot be implicitly constructed by a single iterator.

---

Also, the overload of `std::transform` that you're trying to call is not the right one, as it accepts an `UnaryOperation` while `std::multiplies` is a `BinaryOperation`. You need this overload:

```
template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt, class BinaryOperation >
OutputIt transform( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, 
                    OutputIt d_first, BinaryOperation binary_op );
```

The following code will compile and work:

```
auto vectorMultiplication(const std::vector<float>& v1, const std::vector<float>& v2)
{
    std::vector<float> result;
    std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 
                   std::back_inserter(result), std::multiplies<float>());
    return result;
}
```

[**coliru example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a565849f229e460)

---

Usage example:

```
std::vector<float> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<float> v2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};

auto vm = vectorMultiplication(v1, v2);
for(const auto& x : vm) std::cout << x << " ";
```

Will print:

> 1 4 9 16

Comment: Why not just make it a void function?

Comment: however it still fails on `std::mulitplies`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3de8a67d82cc70a Any guess on that?

Comment: @pergy: I didn't look at the code carefully enough. Another form of `std::transform` has to be invoked... (fixing)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Now I get it! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error is that `return std::transform(...);` tries to return the resulting output iterator, but your function is declared to return `vector<float>`. You need to work out what you actually want to return, because it's not really clear here. Maybe just `void`, and remove the `return` keyword completely?

But you actually want to apply the function to an element from `v1` and an element of `v2` at the same time. The form of `transform` you are trying to use does not do this. There is another form that does, but it's going to be a bit confusing here:

```
std::transform(v1.begin(), // start of first input range
               v1.end(),   // end of first input range
               v2.begin(), // start of **second input** range
               v2.begin(), // start of **output** range
               std::multiplies<float>());
```

See [version 3 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

To do this, you need to be sure that `v1.size() <= v2.size()`.

[Click here for a working example](https://ideone.com/LvnFxA).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obvious from the compiler's error message. The return type of `std::transform` is an iterator, not a container.

The call

```
 std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), std::multiplies<float>() );
```

updates `v2` so that its elements contain the result of the element-wise multiplications.

You may change the return value of the function to `void`:

```
void vectorMultiplication(vector <float> &v1, vector <float> &v2)
{
   std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), std::multiplies<float>() );
}
```

or return `v2`:

```
vector <float> vectorMultiplication(vector <float> &v1, vector <float> &v2)
{
   std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), std::multiplies<float>() );
   return v2;
}
```